# Javascript - Create dynamic index of numeric array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
var a= [[1, 2, [6, 7, 8]], 4, 5];
```

and another array that indicates a specific element by describing the index:

```
var index= [0, 2, 2 ]; // = 8 in a
```

What i need is use variable "index" to create the index of "a" and replace the correspondent element (8) with another value, for example "hello".

How can i do?

Comment: `a[index[0]][index[1]][index[2]]` or do you need a more general solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate the `index` array without the last element (using [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)), and get the sub array. [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the text to last index inside the sub array:

```js
const index = [0, 2, 2 ]; // = 8 in a
const a = [[1, 2, [6, 7, 8]], 4, 5];

const updateIndex = (arr, index, replacement) => {
  index
    .slice(0, -1)
    .reduce((c, i) => c[i], arr)
    .splice(index[index.length -1], 1, replacement);
}

updateIndex(a, index, 'hello');

console.log(a);
```

Comment: can you explain me what exactly means c[i], arr. sorry i am new in javascript

Comment: @topogigio - Get the item in array place `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically each index of index array represents a level of nesting and the value at index represents the index of array in which target element lies or the index of target element itself if it is last element of array index. The problem can be easily solved recursively

For simplicity, I am calling index array, path

```
var path = [0, 2, 2]

var values = [[1, 2, [6, 7, 8]], 4, 5];

function findValues(path, values) {
  //base case, if length = 1 we have the index of target element
  if(path.length == 1) {
    var targetIndex = path[0]
    //read it
    console.log(values[path]) //8
    // modify it 
    values[path] = 'hello'
  } else {
    // pick the current nesting level
    var currentLevel = path.shift()
    // go one level down
    findValues(path, values[currentLevel])
  }
} 

findValues(path, values)

console.log(values) // [[1, 2, [6, 7, "hello"]], 4, 5]
```

Ofcouse the function assumes that path and values array are in valid state i.e. target element exists on the given path, you might want to modify this function to validate input and handle edge cases

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that accesses the desired array and changes the value.

Take a look:

```js
var index = [0, 2, 2 ]; // = 8 in a
var a = [[1, 2, [6, 7, 8]], 4, 5];

function updateIndex(arr, index, value) {
  var elementIndex = index.pop();
  var tempArray = a;
  index.forEach(item => tempArray = tempArray[item]);
  tempArray[elementIndex] = value;
}

updateIndex(a, index, 'hello');

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function which uses a vopy of `indices` and save the `last` index for accessing the reduced array for assignment of the `value`.

This proposal creates missing arrays as well.

```js
function setValue(array, [...indices], value) {
    var last = indices.pop();    
    indices.reduce((a, i) => a[i] = a[i] || [], array)[last] = value;
}

var array = [[1, 2, [6, 7, 8]], 4, 5];

setValue(array, [0, 2, 2 ], 'hello'); // targetting 8

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```